Is it possible to extract deamination patterns from VCF files?
I have some FASTQs from ancient DNA, and I can run them on mapDamage to get the damage profile and use the parameters generated as input to my ML model that try to infer samples' ages.
I also have access to VCF files from ancient DNA. My doubt is if the variant calls from ancient DNA samples in a VCF file (Or other equivalent variant calling formats) reflect the deamination pattern (C to T substitution) that is related to the sample age. If yes, I could try to use these, along with their positions on the chromossomes, to try to infer the age of the samples based on these features.
This is the data I have (Currently transformed to VCF format locally): https://reich.hms.harvard.edu/allen-ancient-dna-resource-aadr-downloadable-genotypes-present-day-and-ancient-dna-data
It is the largest dataset I've found, so I'd really like to work around it as much as possible to extract the most of it! Any tip is welcome!
